# moving from c++ opencv to c# emgu cv?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I'm new on c# i want to translate this code from c++ to c#. The program consist on  determinig if the image is white or not that's why i try to get the value of all the pixel and comparing it with the 0.

```
     int image_blanche(char * str, double prctage){
   Mat img=imread(str);
   int compt=0;
   for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<img.cols;j++){
            if (img.at<uchar>(i,j)==0){
            compt=compt+1;
           }
       }
    }

    if (compt< img.rows*img.cols*prctage)
    {   
        return 1;
    }
   else if (compt> img.rows*img.cols*prctage){
        return 0;
   }
}
```

i proced like this but it still don't working

```
      int Image_blanche(String str,int prctge)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(str);
        int compt = 0;
        int i;
        int j;
        for (  i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
            {
                Bgr color = img[i, j];
                if ((Math.Abs(color.Green - 0) < 0) &&(Math.Abs(color.Blue - 0) < 0)&&(Math.Abs(color.Red - 0) < 0))
                {
                    compt = compt + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return compt <= img.Width*img.Height*prctge ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

Any help please.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 0 from the colors, and if you are trying to see if the image is white, shouldn't you be comparing to 255?

Comment: my problem is how can i get the value of the pixel on c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried opening the image as a Bitmap?

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(file path);
```

Then you you have the method

```
Color c = img.GetPixel(x,y)
```

Well if an image is pure white, then every pixel must equal 255 (for an 8 bit greyscale image), or [255 255 255] (for an 8 bit color image). So you could loop through the rows and columns of the image and count the values at each pixel. Once you have the total, compare it to the total of how many there would be in a white image of the same size i.e. width*height*255 for a greyscale image, or width*height*255*3 for a color image. You could also get the percentage of whiteness in your test image by dividing the count by the total for a white image. i.e. test_img_total / width*height*255*3

Comment: about the comaparaison between the color and the white 255 or black pixel 0 . How can i do it